# How can I help an AQL plan in selecting an index?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I have multiple persistent indexes on a collection.  One is a timestamp, and the other is a document id. The timestamp is used to select a range of documents.  I need to retrieve documents by a range of time over a list of document ids.  The AQL would be something like this:

`for x in collection filter time1>=x.timestamp&&time2<x.timestamp&&x.id in [<list of ids>] return x`

ArangoDB always chooses the timestamp for the index but in most cases, the id should filter more objects initially.

**How can I direct the planner to choose the id index over the timestamp one?  Alternatively, is there a way to create a combined index that would reduce or eliminate a linear scan for this type of query?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad 1) Use multiple filter lines to help the execution planner:

```
FOR x IN collection
  FILTER x.id IN [1,2,3]
  FILTER x.timestamp < @time1 AND
         x.timestamp >= @time2
  RETURN x
```

Ad 2)
This depends on how you create the indices; in javascript it's as simple as:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({type: "hash", fields: ["id", "timestamp]"]});
```

[More details in the index documention](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/indexing-working-with-indexes.html#creating-an-index)

Comment: It came to me that this might help.  I tried some different ways of indexing and filtering but the difference in performance was small.  I ended up re-architecting the approach which ended up with a ~10x performance improvement,  This new approach minimized the number of AQLs needed to retrieve the info by doing breadth first instead of depth first requests.